# i have a ticking/clicking as i accelerate and there seems to be loss of torque as if the clutch is slipping

Tags: engine

I was driving home and noticed a tapping noise as I accelerate and came with a loss of torque as if the clutch was slipping?

Comment: Ticking could be an indicator of timing belt going bad

Comment: What kind of vehicle? You might be low on oil-maybe a leak. Also one of the cylinder’s lifters could be bad. Is your check engine light on?